# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy' error observer while i do running the docker images

Tags: flask

I am getting `ModuleNotFoundError` `No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'` when try to docker run of builded docker images.The same python flask run using terminal is working fine for me but not in docker?

```
FROM python:3.6
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install flask gunicorn
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8000", "app"]
```

Comment: You're only installing gunicorn in the docker image; so of course the flask_sqlalchemy module won't be found

Comment: Matt Healy i have add these "RUN pip3 install flask SQLAlchemy" in dockerfile still facing issue

Comment: Ok, so that's installing the flask package and the SQLAlchemy package. But what about flask_sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 0):

The good practice is to save file with installed pip packages, e.g. in `requirements.txt`. (preferably with only needed packages, e.g. when you are using pyevn).

This is done by `pip freeze > requirements.txt` (when located on local machine, in terminal).

Then, all you should do is replace `RUN pip install flask gunicorn` with `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` and all installed packages on the local machine will be installed in the docker too.